# Python/matplotlib plot values jump at discontinuity in gradient

Tags: python, matplotlib, gradient

I'm trying to graph the output from a physics calculation, using python's matplotlib, however the plots that my program generates don't make sense to me. What I want to plot are three equations, 1/a1, 1/a2 and 1/a3, whose gradients change at the point mn, however my code as it is now causes the values as well as the gradients to change.

It seems that the equations for a1, a2, a3 become much larger when the functions switch from the ms < mn definition to the ms >= mn definition, however trying them with test values like a1(10e11, mn) doesn't show any large change.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mn = 10312054216.046213
mz = 91.1876
a1z = 98.330 #NOTE: these values are for inverses of aplha at mz, ie 1/a1, etc
a2z = 29.571
a3z = 8.396
b1, b2, b3 = -13/(4*pi), 19/(12*pi), 7/(2*pi)
b1p, b2p, b3p = -157/(36*pi), 11/(12*pi), 17/(6*pi) #above new physics scale
c1, c2, c3 = 3/5, 1, 1

ms = np.linspace(10e8, 10e11, num = 1000000, endpoint = True)

def a1(ms, mn):
    if (ms < mn):
        return ( c1*(a1z + b1*np.log(ms/mz)) )**(-1)
    elif (ms >= mn):
        a1n = ( c1*(a1z + b1*log(mn/mz)) )**(-1)
        return ( c1*(a1n + b1p*log(ms/mn)) )**(-1)

def a2(ms, mn):
    if (ms < mn):
        return ( c2*(a2z + b2*np.log(ms/mz)) )**(-1)
    elif (ms >= mn):
        a2n = ( c2*(a2z + b2*log(mn/mz)) )**(-1)
        return ( c2*(a2n + b2p*log(ms/mn)) )**(-1)

def a3(ms, mn):
    if (ms < mn):
        return ( c3*(a3z + b3*np.log(ms/mz)) )**(-1)
    elif (ms >= mn):
        a3n = ( c3*(a3z + b3*log(mn/mz)) )**(-1)
        return ( c3*(a3n + b3p*log(ms/mn)) )**(-1)

plt.xscale('log')
plt.plot(ms, [1/a1(x, mn) for x in ms])
plt.plot(ms, [1/a2(x, mn) for x in ms])
plt.plot(ms, [1/a3(x, mn) for x in ms])

plt.show()
```

Any insight here would be very welcome, thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what is your question. Do you want us to debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem from programming point of view. From math of view, however, you have equations of type y=A*x+B and those are straight lines. The difference between situations when ms>=mz and ms < mz lies in both A and B, so not only do the slopes differ, the y-axe offsets are also as well. If that's not meant to happen, than there's a math problem with your equations.

Comment: I see! Thank you for your help, I'll have to revise my equations.